# Extract rows with similar rownames from two files

Tags: r, subset

In R, how can extract rows with identical row names from two data frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two data frames `d1` and `d2`, the row names that are identical in both are given by `intersect(rownames(d1), rownames(d2))`. So you can do for example `d1[intersect(rownames(d1), rownames(d2)), ]` and get rows in `d1` that exist in `d2`